# Select data from dual table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data as following:
1203
1222
3201
4300
Which are numbers of products, so i need to select them as a data in table ..
I think the solution will be with using dual table ..
I tried the following code:

```
Select * from { values '1203','1222','3201','4300'} as Table1
```

But it not working !

Comment: No, they will be selected as table but i need them as rows

Comment: _"it not working !"_ is a useless problem description. Why not? What happened? What did you want to happen instead? You probably got a specific error that indicates what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle has the `TABLE` function, which takes as input a varray and returns an anonymous table (anonymous means "the table doesn't have a name"), with a single column named `column_value`.

Oracle also has the function `sys.odcinumberlist()`, which takes as input a comma-separated list of numbers and returns a varray of numbers. (Similarly, to generate a varray of varchar2 values, there is `sys.odcivarchar2list()`.)

To input your for values and return a result with a single column named `num` (or any other name you want), you can use these two functions together - and alias the column in the `select` clause. Like this:

```
select column_value as num
from   table( sys.odcinumberlist( 1203, 1222, 3201, 4300 ) )
;

   NUM
  ----
  1203
  1222
  3201
  4300
```

Answer (score 3):

In **standard** SQL you would need to use:

```
Select * 
from (values ('1203','1222','3201','4300')) as Table1;
```

That would create a single row with four (character) columns. If you intended to return four **rows** it *would* be:

```
Select * 
from (values ('1203'),('1222'),('3201'),('4300')) as Table1
```

However, Oracle does **NOT** support that syntax. Neither does it support a SELECT without a FROM clause.

If you want a single row with 4 columns in Oracle you need

```
select '1203','1222','3201','4300'
from dual;
```

If you want four **rows** you need

```
select '1203'
from dual
union all
select '1222'
from dual
union all
select '3201'
from dual
union all
select '4300'
from dual;
```

---

Additionally: `'1203'` is **not** a "number". It's a character string. Number literals are written *without* quotes in SQL: `1203` is a number

Comment: You "need" is a bit too strong; there are other ways that don't use the DUAL table.

Comment: adding dual to each number product is a bit tedious

Comment: With that said: I see that someone downvoted the answer (without leaving an explanation). That isn't from me, and I disagree with the downvote: your answer is absolutely correct. Whoever downvoted should explain their reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `XMLTABLE`.

```
select TO_NUMBER(TRIM(COLUMN_VALUE)) as numbers from  XMLTABLE( '1203,1222,3201,4300');

Numbers
-------
1203
1222
3201
4300
```

This works only for numbers.

EDIT: Better to wrap it with `to_number` as suggested by experts in the comments.

Comment: And, strictly speaking, this returns strings, not numbers; to return numbers, you need to further wrap within `to_number()`.

Comment: @mathguy: "really" strictly speaking this returns values of type `XMLTYPE`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - no, it returns values of type `VARCHAR2`. `COLUMN_VALUE` is `XMLTYPE`, but `TRIM()` applied to `XMLTYPE` returns `VARCHAR2`. You can see that by wrapping `TRIM(COLUMN_VALUE)` within `DUMP()`.